# ExpandableListView error show?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image: to the left the xml in eclipse, to the right the emulator]

I have designed my interface for my ExpandableListView but in the emulator appear two black line vertical, why?

I have designed the rectangle, but when the description inside is long the rectangle expand but the graphics appear not proportionate.
I have read this article http://adilsoomro.blogspot.it/2012/11/android-how-to-use-9-patch-png.html
but I have't understand how to use the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 9-patch program helps you mark areas in an image that will be stretched. You select horizontal and vertical "zones" that will be sort of replicated when stretching is applied on your image. Just spend some time with the editor. It's pretty simple.

EDIT: If you still find it difficult, try [this](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) link.